# Android Things: is NDK supported?

Tags: android-ndk, iot, gpio, android-things

With the Developer Preview only supporting Java Applications on Android Things I am curious to know if native applications can also be run on this platform.

Mainly due to 2 reasons.

1. Embedded devices have a large support for sensors many of which are written in C/C++. Here's one for example: https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/upm. With NDK, wouldn't this be easier to integrate into Android Things rather than rewriting the same sensor drivers in Java?
2. It would also be very interesting to compare the speed characteristics of running Native Apps to Java ones utilizing Peripheral Manager APIs for GPIO/I2C/SPI etc.

Comment: Drivers should be written in C in kernel. Most of them.

Comment: Google says we can't write device drivers. I wonder what are the options beyond recompiling kernel. Though I noticed pwm and i2c things under /dev (or was it /sys ?). Not sure how to listen for interrupts though.

Comment: It is now possible to compare Java/Kotlin PIO APIs and [Native PIO APIs](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/native).

Answer (score 1):

> With the Developer Preview only supporting Java Applications on Android Things I am curious to know if native applications can also be run on this platform.

You can build and run apps with native support in *Android Things*. Simply create a project in *Android Studio* with C++ support and run.

> It would also be very interesting to compare the speed characteristics of running Native Apps to Java ones utilizing Peripheral Manager APIs for GPIO/I2C/SPI etc.

It is possible to compare *Java*/*Kotlin* PIO APIs and [Native PIO APIs](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/native).